# Is there a filter for editor-style.css file?

Tags: css, editor, wysiwyg, add-editor-style

I need to add multiple css files from a css framework to my editor-style.css file. The point is that i don't want to update the editor-style.css file anytime there's a new update from either my theme or the css framework. Is there a filter or hook **to add more than one stylesheet**? (I'm aware of `@import`, but didnt try to use it here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_editor_style( $stylesheet );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Comment: Mpf. I haven't taken a look at the codex... Thanks for the heads up.